# What software-visible processor state needs to go in a jmp_buf on an x86-64 processor?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, setjmp

As stated, what software-visible processor state needs to go in a `jmp_buf` on an x86-64 processor when `setjmp(jmp_buf env)` is called? What processor state does not?

I have been reading a lot about `setjmp` and `longjmp` but couldn't find a clear answer to my question. I know it is implementation dependent but I would like to know for the x86_64 architecture.

From the [following implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S) 
it seems that on an x86-64 machine all the callee saved registers (`%r12-%r15`, `%rbp`, `%rbx`) need to be saved as well as the stack pointer, program counter and all the saved arguments of the current environment. However I'm not sure about that, hope someone could clarify that for me.

Comment: If that glibc implementation says so, what makes you think it's not correct?

Comment: I'm just not sure about my understanding of the code since I'm rather new to assembly and C.

Comment: Are you asking whether that's what glibc does, or whether what glibc does is correct, or something else?

Comment: I'm asking in general what processor state needs to go in a jmp_buf on an x86-64 architecture. Not what glibc does or if it is correct. For example, which x86-64 registers need to be saved? What about condition flags? For example, I think the floating point registers do not need to be saved because they don't contribute to the state of the program.

Comment: It might be easier to ask what won't get saved. All the caller saved registers will not be saved. calling `setjmp` is like any other function. The caller has to preserve the caller registers (volatile) before calling `setjmp`. On x86-64 (and x86) This data usually gets saved to the stack by pushing or storing them to non-volatile registers. Because this data is already saved, the `jmp_buf` needs to concern itself with saving all the non-volatile (callee saved) registers.

Comment: Generally all the flags get restored as they were as it is easier to restore them all than individual ones. But at a minimum the direction flag must be 0 (forward) on exit from a function. The x87 control word is nonvolatile (callee saved) so it to must be restored. All the x87 registers are volatile (thus caller saved) so they don't need to be saved by setjmp. Since MMX registers are mapped onto x87 registers they too don't need to be savedas they too are caller saved (volatile registers).

Comment: The best place to understand what is non-volatile and must e saved by setjmp is the [64-bit Linux System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf).

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you a lot this actually helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, which x86-64 registers need to be saved? What about condition flags? For example, I think the floating point registers do not need to be saved because they don't contribute to the state of the program.

That's because of the calling convention.  `setjmp` is a function-call that can return multiple times (the first time when you actually call it, later times when a child function calls `longjmp`), but it's still a function call.  Like any function call, the compiler assumes that all call-clobbered registers have been clobbered, so `longjmp` doesn't need to restore them.

So yes, they're not part of the "program state" on a function call boundary because the compiler-generated asm is definitely not keeping any values in them.

You're looking at glibc's implementation for the x86-64 System V ABI, where *all* vector / x87 registers are call-clobbered and thus don't have to be saved.

In the Windows x86-64 calling convention, xmm6-15 are call-preserved (just the low 128 bits, not the upper portions of y/zmm6-15), and would have to be part of the `jmp_buf`.

i.e. it's not the CPU architecture that's relevant here, it's the software calling convention.

---

Besides the call-preserved registers, one key thing is that it's only legal to `longjmp` to a `jmp_buf` saved by a parent function, not from any arbitrary function after the function that called `setjmp` has returned.

If `setjmp` had to support that, it would have to save the entire stack frame, or actually (for the function to be able to return, and that parent to be able to return, etc.) the whole stack all the way up to the top.  This is obviously insane, and thus it's clear why `longjmp` has that restriction of only being able to jump to parent / (great) grandparent functions, so it just has to restore the stack pointer to point at the still-existing stack frame and restore whatever local variables in that function might have been modified since `setjmp`.

(On C / C++ implementations on architectures / calling conventions that use something other than a normal call-stack, a similar argument about the jump-target function being able to return still applies.)

Answer (score 0):

As the `jmp_buf` is the only place that can be used to restore processor state on a `longjmp`, it's generally everything that is needed to restore the full state of the machine as it was when `setjmp`is called.

This obviously depends very much on the processor and the compiler (what exactly does it use of the CPU's features to store program state):

- On an ideal pure-stack machine that holds information of CPU state nowhere but the stack, that would be the stack pointer only. Other than in very old or purely academical implementations, such machines do rarely exist. You could, however, write a compiler on a modern machine like an x86 that solely uses the stack to store such information. For such a hypothetical compiler, saving the stack pointer only would suffice to restore program state.
- On a more common, practical machine, this might be the stack pointer and the full set of registers used to store program status.
- On some CPUs that store program status information in other places, for example in a zero page, and compilers that make use of such CPU features, the `jmp_buff` would also need to store a copy of this zero page (certain 65xx CPUs or ATmel AVR MCUs and their compilers might use this feature)

Comment: Thank you! This makes it clearer. But on a practical machine, like the x86-64 architecture, would we really need to save the full set of registers? Also the floating point registers, flag status, etc.?

Comment: you didn't read the second paragraph, especially the part in parentheses.

Comment: I did but I was hoping there was a more concrete answer for a concrete x86-64 GNU C compiler for example or similar. Just to get an idea what might be important to have in the jmp_buf and of what the program state/environment might consist of.